# How to commit the staged files and excluding modified files

Tags: git

I thought git commit will only commit the staged file to repo,

`git ci a.txt`

Then the modified `a.txt` (content: b) was committed to the repo, but not the staged `a.txt` (content: a)

So What's the command can git commits the staged file to repo , and keep the modified file as usual.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `git commit` (without a pathspec) you only commit staged changes. So, in order not to commit the new changes to `a.txt`, instead of doing `git ci a.txt` just do `git commit`, which will not commit the new unstaged changes.

Comment: But there are 2 files `a.txt` and `vimrc`, if I type `git ci` those 2 staged files will be committed, how to commit the staged `a.txt` only ? thanks

Comment: In that case, you should unstage the `vimrc` file. `git reset HEAD vimrc` will do that for you, check that the help message that shows when you do `git status` says exactly that.

Comment: So there is no way to commit partial `STAGED FILES` , right ?

Comment: Once you staged them, then I don't think there's a way to do that. But you can partially stage files. If you do `git add -p a.txt`, it will go through each hunk and allow you to decide wether to stage it or not.

Comment: @newBike a workaround is `git stash --keep-index && git commit a.txt && git stash pop`. NB that the stash will have the current `HEAD` as parent and `git stash pop` will result in a merge conflict on files that have a line both staged and unstaged

Answer (score 1):

```
$git add a.txt
```

This will add the a file to git which means git will start tracking this file for any changes. This operation is done only for new files created. `$git add .` will add all the files present in that folder level.

Now 
   `git commit -m "Initial commit` .

This commits the current file and pushes it to staging area. In case you have old files say `b.txt and c.txt` which contain changes and have already been tracked by git. You need to commit them separately

```
`git commit -m "Issues fixed /path/b.txt /path/c.txt`
```

Now take a pull in case the remote repo has changed `$git pull` and then `$git push`. The push will send all the three files `a.txt, b.txt and c.txt` to the remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make to an already staged file will not be staged themselves. You have to explicitly stage them.

Answer (score 0):

`git commit -- PATHSPEC` creates a commit containing the current checked out version of the files matched by that `REFSPEC` (ie: both staged and unstaged).

This is somewhat counter-intuative as reglar `git commit` creates a commit of staged changes and one might expect `git commit -- PATHSPEC` to do the same but only include certain files.

One workaround is to first `git stash --keep-index` then `git commit -- a.txt`, then `git stash pop`. This will result in a merge conflict however in the (uncommon) case where the same line is both staged and unstaged.